# WebView Back, Refresh, Forward? Simply doesn't work!

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, webview, options-menu

I have tried everything to get my 'forward' and 'back' to work.

Refresh is working [I figured it out by changing the method to read 'webView.reload();' instead of 'webView.refresh();'

Can anyone assist with the forward and back? I have tried 'forward', 'canGoForward' and 'goForward' as well as 'back', 'canGoBack' and 'goBack'. There are no error codes however none of those methods actually do anything.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); // Add menu items, second value is the id, use this in the onCreateOptionsMenu
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Back");
    menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Refresh");
    menu.add(0, 3, 0, "Forward");
    return true; // End of menu configuration
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){ // Called when you tap a menu item
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case 1: //If the ID equals 1, go back
            webView.goBack();
        return true;
        case 2 : //If the ID equals 2, refresh
            webView.reload();
        return true;
        case 3: //If the ID equals 3, go forward
            webView.goForward();
        return true;
        }
    return false;
    }
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { // Enables browsing to previous pages with the hardware back button
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) { // Check if the key event was the BACK key and if there's history
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }   // If it wasn't the BACK key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you shared doesn't include the portion where you are creating webview and navigating between urls. So I am just taking a guess at what might be happening.

It seems that `webview` is an instance field of your class whose portion you have shown in the question.  Could it be that `webView` is being recreated every time you navigate to a new page? That is, the code is something like:

```
webview = new WebView(this);
webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");
```

If this is what is being done, all you need is to create the 'webView' once and just call `loadUrl` everytime you need to navigate to new url. This way the webview instance will be able to retain the history.

Comment: Thanks, I just repaired the loadUrl as recommended and it worked great! You are wonderful!