# Stop and reload buttons for android webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm a bit new to Android programming so bear with me if I'm not 100% correct on how i phrase my questions. I'm looking for an a way to stop and reload my Android webView. The webView takes the user to a a simple HTML link, which works. Now I want to implement stop, reload, forward, and back buttons for the webView. What I did for the back and forward functions was very simple-- I simply created an onKeyDown function to facilitate going forward and backward as shown below:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FORWARD) && mWebView.canGoForward())
    {
        mWebView.goForward();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Now for reloading (refreshing) this webView and stopping this webView from loading is my trouble. I know for reloading a webView you could simply create a new setOnClickListener function and reload the URL. I'm not so sure about stopping a webView from loading. Do I have to create individual buttons for reloading/stopping the webView? Or is there a prebuilt function I can place inside my code that can help me do so? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Check out the similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211473/webview-back-refresh-forward-simply-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Reload***

```
mWebview.loadUrl("http://twitter.com"); //calling again `loadUrl()` with `url` gives your refresh type effects.
```

I think there ain't any method like reloadUrl.

***Stop Loading***

`stopLoading ()`: Stops the current load.

```
mWebView.stopLoading();
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great. Just wondering--would I have to create individual buttons that you'd have to click for Android to refresh or stop a page? Or is there something prebuilt, similar to onKeyDown as shown above that could do it for me?

Comment: I'm afraid but there isn't any pre-built button or something like that. So you have to individual create those button.

Answer (score 0):

**Reloading the WebView**

```
mWebView.reload();
```

**Stop loading URL**

```
mWebView.stopLoading ()
```

*it will 100% work*