# Android WebView Crash on calling WebView.reload() function

Tags: android, webview, reload

I have used android webview control to load any website. When i call "WebView.reload()" function for "http://us.cnn.com/?hpt=ed_US" web then my application is restarted without any crasher.

Following is output from logcat after calling WebView.reload() function....

```
--------------------------------------------------
03-29 17:08:02.767: A/libc(30401): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 30421 (WebViewCoreThre)
03-29 17:08:02.867: I/DEBUG(124): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-29 17:08:02.867: I/DEBUG(124): Build fingerprint: 'google/nakasi/grouper:4.2.1/JOP40D/533553:user/release-keys'
03-29 17:08:02.877: I/DEBUG(124): Revision: '0'
03-29 17:08:02.877: I/DEBUG(124): pid: 30401, tid: 30421, name: WebViewCoreThre  >>> com.mkyong.android <<<
03-29 17:08:02.877: I/DEBUG(124): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     r0 00000000  r1 00000001  r2 00000025  r3 00000000
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     r4 645a4fc8  r5 400ae228  r6 645a4fd4  r7 6753547e
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     r8 00098b14  r9 00098369  sl 400ae228  fp 00000000
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     ip 673de668  sp 699140a0  lr 6747f89f  pc 674b3e30  cpsr 20000030
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d0  0000000740e00000  d1  0000000800000002
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d2  40e0000000000000  d3  0000000700000007
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d4  bf83c1f24249f0b1  d5  3ff0000000000000
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d6  3f80000000000000  d7  3e8000003e924925
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d16 0000000000000217  d17 00000080b280e580
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d18 0000000000000091  d19 bf66bee65473ab90
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d20 3fc553ad8b79a5cc  d21 3e66376972bea4d0
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d22 41224f7ffffffffe  d23 bfc27bfffffffff4
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d24 3ff24f7ffffffffe  d25 3fe555555575584a
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d26 0000000500000004  d27 0000000700000006
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d28 0004800000000000  d29 000d800000090000
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     d30 0000000100000001  d31 0000000100000001
03-29 17:08:02.967: I/DEBUG(124):     scr 20000090
03-29 17:08:02.977: I/DEBUG(124): backtrace:
03-29 17:08:02.977: I/DEBUG(124):     #00  pc 000c1e30  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (net::HttpCache::Transaction::DoCacheReadData()+151)
03-29 17:08:02.977: I/DEBUG(124):     #01  pc 000c43a3  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (net::HttpCache::Transaction::DoLoop(int)+1966)
03-29 17:08:02.977: I/DEBUG(124):     #02  pc 000c475d  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (net::HttpCache::Transaction::Read(net::IOBuffer*, int, CallbackRunner<Tuple1<int> >*)+512)
03-29 17:08:02.977: I/DEBUG(124):     #03  pc 001074ef  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #04  pc 0010a625  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #05  pc 0010a6fb  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #06  pc 0010ab05  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #07  pc 0010af6f  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #08  pc 00102155  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (net::URLRequest::Read(net::IOBuffer*, int, int*)+208)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #09  pc 002366b9  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #10  pc 002367e7  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #11  pc 0010ad5f  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #12  pc 00107595  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #13  pc 0007cb8b  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #14  pc 000c1bd3  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (net::HttpCache::Transaction::DoCallback(int)+138)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #15  pc 000c1c4f  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (net::HttpCache::Transaction::HandleResult(int)+82)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #16  pc 000c4425  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (net::HttpCache::Transaction::DoLoop(int)+2096)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #17  pc 0007cb8b  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #18  pc 000ad1bd  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #19  pc 000ada9d  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #20  pc 000797cd  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #21  pc 0005643d  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::RunTask(Task*)+180)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #22  pc 000575b3  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask(MessageLoop::PendingTask const&)+18)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #23  pc 00057623  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::DoWork()+94)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #24  pc 00058367  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #25  pc 00056b13  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::RunInternal()+114)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #26  pc 00056b71  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::Run()+16)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #27  pc 000771d9  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (base::Thread::ThreadMain()+188)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #28  pc 00076c93  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #29  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #30  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124): stack:
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914060  400ae228  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914064  6744951b  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::PostTask_Helper(tracked_objects::Location const&, Task*, long long, bool)+250)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914068  ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          6991406c  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914070  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914074  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914078  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          6991407c  40058420  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914080  64930890  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914084  400ae228  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914088  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          6991408c  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914090  00000002  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914094  6747f89f  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914098  df0027ad  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          6991409c  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #00  699140a0  64488630  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140a4  674b3a35  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (net::HttpCache::Transaction::DoNetworkReadComplete(int)+88)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140a8  675938b8  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140ac  400ae228  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140b0  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140b4  674d25a5  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140b8  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140bc  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140c0  40058420  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140c4  699140f4  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140c8  69917ea0  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140cc  674480c1  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (base::WaitableEvent::~WaitableEvent()+14)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140d0  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140d4  69917dd0  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140d8  400ae228  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          699140dc  4d17f9e5  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          ........  ........
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):     #01  69914160  00000001  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914164  69914184  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914168  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          6991416c  64b95fe0  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914170  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914174  674aff03  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (net::HttpCache::ProcessPendingQueue(net::HttpCache::ActiveEntry*)+146)
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914178  64570600  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          6991417c  674b11d5  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (net::HttpCache::OnProcessPendingQueue(net::HttpCache::ActiveEntry*))
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914180  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914184  64570600  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          69914188  40058390  
03-29 17:08:02.987: I/DEBUG(124):          6991418c  6758200a  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69914190  6754e9bc  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69914194  000003df  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69914198  64b95fe8  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          6991419c  64b95fe8  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          ........  ........
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):     #02  699150f0  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          699150f4  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          699150f8  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          699150fc  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69915100  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69915104  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69915108  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          6991510c  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69915110  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69915114  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69915118  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          6991511c  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69915120  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69915124  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          69915128  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          6991512c  00000000  
03-29 17:08:02.997: I/DEBUG(124):          ........  ........
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r4:
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4fa8 00000368 0000001a 65005200 75006700  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4fb8 61006c00 00007200 00000018 000001db  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4fc8 67590368 00000027 645a4798 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4fd8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4fe8 64b975b4 00000000 00000000 645a4fe4  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4ff8 645a4fe4 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5008 00000000 645a4ffc 645a4ffc 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5018 6494ada8 40058390 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5028 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5038 00000000 00000000 00000001 312e3239  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5048 312e3232 322e3632 00003135 645a5052  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5058 645a5044 00000050 fba373d9 002e37a4  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5068 fba92504 002e37a4 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5078 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5088 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5098 63349f80 2e8ebf73 f70980a1 dd73c656  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r5:
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae208 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae218 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae228 4d17f9e5 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae238 00000007 00000002 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae248 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae258 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae268 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae278 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae288 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae298 00000000 00000000 00824591 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00004000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r6:
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4fb4 75006700 61006c00 00007200 00000018  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4fc4 000001db 67590368 00000027 645a4798  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4fd4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4fe4 00000000 64b975b4 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a4ff4 645a4fe4 645a4fe4 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5004 00000000 00000000 645a4ffc 645a4ffc  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5014 00000000 6494ada8 40058390 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5024 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5034 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001  
03-29 17:08:03.007: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5044 312e3239 312e3232 322e3632 00003135  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5054 645a5052 645a5044 00000050 fba373d9  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5064 002e37a4 fba92504 002e37a4 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5074 00000000 00000000 00000000 ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5084 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     645a5094 00000000 63349f80 2e8ebf73 f70980a1  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     645a50a4 dd73c656 7bc5b2b6 00000001 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r7:
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     6753545c 632f6c61 6d6f7268 2f6d7569 676f6f67  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     6753546c 7275656c 72732f6c 75672f63 632e6c72  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     6753547c 68430063 206b6365 6c696166 203a6465  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     6753548c 736c6166 00202e65 69797254 7420676e  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     6753549c 6567206f 68742074 70732065 6f206365  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     675354ac 6e612066 766e6920 64696c61 4c525520  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     675354bc 68430021 206b6365 6c696166 203a6465  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     675354cc 73726170 2e5f6465 68746170 6e656c2e  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     675354dc 30203e20 4300202e 6e6f6e61 6c616369  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     675354ec 74617020 6f662068 65722072 73657571  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     675354fc 73207374 6c756f68 65622064 6e6f6e20  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     6753550c 706d652d 65007974 72657478 2f6c616e  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     6753551c 6f726863 6d75696d 6f6f672f 75656c67  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     6753552c 732f6c72 752f6372 635f6c72 6e6f6e61  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     6753553c 746e695f 616e7265 00682e6c 656c6966  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     6753554c 002f2f3a 65747865 6c616e72 7268632f  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r8:
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098af4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098b04 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098b14 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098b24 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098b34 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098b44 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098b54 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098b64 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098b74 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098b84 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098b94 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098ba4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098bb4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098bc4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098bd4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098be4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r9:
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098348 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098358 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098368 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098378 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098388 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098398 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     000983a8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     000983b8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     000983c8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     000983d8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     000983e8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     000983f8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098408 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098418 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098428 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     00098438 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124): memory near sl:
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae208 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae218 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae228 4d17f9e5 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae238 00000007 00000002 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae248 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae258 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae268 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae278 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae288 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae298 00000000 00000000 00824591 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.017: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     400ae2f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00004000  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124): memory near ip:
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de648 674f4a8d 674f3bd7 674f3ec9 674f3e11  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de658 674f3f8d 674f3d25 674f4229 6747d9b1  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de668 674f4085 67461c7b 67461ccb 67448111  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de678 6746da69 67486419 674f3d95 40947341  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de688 674835f5 674f4f89 67461cb3 67440915  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de698 674360bd 67461ca1 674f424b 674753a1  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de6a8 67435e8d 6747ee75 67435913 674f4d43  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de6b8 674f5669 674f52bd 67447141 67447175  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de6c8 674f46ed 674f51cd 674f5245 6743dcc3  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de6d8 6743dcc3 674f5ddd 674f5e75 674f5d51  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de6e8 674be7f1 67453e79 674bec19 67487191  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de6f8 67435dd1 674f43d1 674f435d 674f3a75  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de708 6748727d 674f3a39 674bf94d 674c0959  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de718 401b3c41 4030f884 4035a504 402f4090  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de728 4035df6c 40624a35 6747334f 67470521  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     673de738 6747313d 674ceda5 402fc67c 402fc528  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124): memory near sp:
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     69914080 64930890 400ae228 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     69914090 00000002 6747f89f df0027ad 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     699140a0 64488630 674b3a35 675938b8 400ae228  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     699140b0 00000000 674d25a5 00000000 00000000  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     699140c0 40058420 699140f4 69917ea0 674480c1  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     699140d0 00000000 69917dd0 400ae228 4d17f9e5  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     699140e0 00000013 6749bc15 6758fbf0 649f2400  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     699140f0 649f2400 00098b14 00098369 400ae228  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     69914100 00000000 674b2a1f c0000000 0000000c  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     69914110 40058404 00000000 c0000000 00000018  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     69914120 00000000 00000000 00000023 400743c3  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     69914130 000006a0 69914178 40058404 4d17f9e5  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     69914140 00000000 00000000 64930890 4d17f9e5  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     69914150 645a4fc8 675938b8 6754eefa 674b63a7  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     69914160 00000001 69914184 00000000 64b95fe0  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     69914170 00000000 674aff03 64570600 674b11d5  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124): code around pc:
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3e10 f8d4fddd 6da301a8 f8d4b150 f8d411c8  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3e20 91002194 f8d46819 f0173198 e00efb71  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3e30 21016818 6198f8d4 21c8f8d4 96006803  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3e40 f8d49201 699e219c 3194f8d4 992b47b0  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3e50 4299682b f780d001 b02ceab8 bf00bd70  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3e60 000de996 000de98e 0009b12c 0009b1c8  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3e70 4604b5f0 b0d54e3f 447e4d3f 447d6836  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3e80 6833682d 2b016828 d1159053 f9e4f793  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3e90 dc112803 b9796da1 f44f4938 23036297  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3ea0 4479a803 ff14f793 a8044935 f7824479  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3eb0 a803f89a fce8f793 2a016832 f793d116  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3ec0 2803f9cb f8d4dc12 b17e60e8 f240492d  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3ed0 230342b9 4479a82b fefaf793 a82c492a  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3ee0 f7824479 a82bf880 fccef793 21236da0  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3ef0 21026061 68036800 47b8695f 20104607  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     674b3f00 ea56f780 46064639 fd94f7c9 1d30b116  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124): code around lr:
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f87c 690b6801 bd084798 bd082002 f7ffb508  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f88c f1d0fff4 bf380001 bd082000 f7ffb508  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f89c 2801ffec 2000bfcc bd082001 4604b570  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f8ac 4616460d 6021b911 e0056061 68c36808  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f8bc 47984608 60606026 462060a5 0000bd70  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f8cc b5104b06 4604447b f8403308 f7b63b0c  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f8dc 4620f8e7 ff58f7ed bd104620 0010ffe4  
03-29 17:08:03.027: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f8ec 4604b510 ffecf7ff f7b44620 4620ed56  
03-29 17:08:03.037: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f8fc 0000bd10 4604b570 460d3004 f7c14616  
03-29 17:08:03.037: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f90c 4b06f803 000cf104 463160a5 3308447b  
03-29 17:08:03.037: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f91c f7be6023 4620f8dc bf00bd70 0010ff9c  
03-29 17:08:03.037: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f92c 4606b570 b08e4c17 6824447c 900d6820  
03-29 17:08:03.037: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f93c f7b42020 4605ed38 f8c4f7de a8014912  
03-29 17:08:03.037: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f94c f7e04479 6832fdfd 4628a901 fe94f7df  
03-29 17:08:03.037: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f95c f7b6a801 490df8a5 4479a807 fdf0f7e0  
03-29 17:08:03.037: I/DEBUG(124):     6747f96c 46286872 f7dfa907 a807fe87 f898f7b6  
03-29 17:08:03.157: I/BootReceiver(450): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-29 17:08:03.177: W/InputDispatcher(450): channel '427086e8 com.mkyong.android/com.mkyong.android.FirstActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-29 17:08:03.177: E/InputDispatcher(450): channel '427086e8 com.mkyong.android/com.mkyong.android.FirstActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-29 17:08:03.217: D/Zygote(126): Process 30401 terminated by signal (11)
03-29 17:08:03.247: D/dalvikvm(450): JIT code cache reset in 5 ms (1048464 bytes 232/1)
03-29 17:08:03.247: D/dalvikvm(450): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1449K, 19% free 19851K/24320K, paused 83ms, total 85ms
03-29 17:08:03.247: W/InputDispatcher(450): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '427086e8 com.mkyong.android/com.mkyong.android.FirstActivity (server)'
03-29 17:08:03.247: I/WindowState(450): WIN DEATH: Window{427086e8 u0 com.mkyong.android/com.mkyong.android.FirstActivity}
03-29 17:08:03.247: I/ActivityManager(450): Process com.mkyong.android (pid 30401) has died.
```

---

My Code is as below

WebView mWebView;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setText("First Activity");
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn1 = null;

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://us.cnn.com/?hpt=ed_US");
}

public void onClick(View v) {
        mWebView.reload();
}
```

Comment: Please try to add the code.

Comment: Thanks kamil for your quick response. As per your request i updated the description with code.

Comment: So, you are getting error when you reload the webview?

Comment: Yes, correct. It loads first time perfect. It works fine for other sites. Just occurs for "http://us.cnn.com/?hpt=ed_US".

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563325/is-there-a-better-way-to-refresh-webview/18823884#18823884][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563325/is-there-a-better-way-to-refresh-webview/18823884#18823884

Answer (score 0):

Please try to call it again like this.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    yourActivtyName.this.mWebView.loadUrl("http://us.cnn.com/?hpt=ed_US");
}
```

Comment: Yes it works fine in onclick. I removed the "mWebView.reload();" and added the script as you suggestted. Why the reload not works?

Comment: Because it try to introduce new history entries

Comment: Please don't forget to tick it as answer :)

Comment: This is no a solution for the bug because i need to call "Reload()" function. May i catch this error. So it does not close my activity. BTW, i already tried the "Try...Catch" statement but it does not work.

Comment: But I thought you got your answer.

Comment: No, i strictly need to call the "Reload" function anyhow. It will be helpful if i can catch this error. Any idea? If i launch the new URL instead of reload then i can't re-sent the submitted data by submitting any form.

Comment: Please see the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211473/webview-back-refresh-forward-simply-doesnt-work). Hope that you will now understand the problem what you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled hardwareaccelerate in you app,may cause this problem.You can disable hardwareaccelerate for WebView by this code webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
Holp this help you.